# Downloading an XML through a url

Tags: android, android-activity

We have an Android app, which we deploy by opening a browser on the device go to the customer url, then the browser downloads the file. We are also trying to download a separate .xml settings file. If I try this with in the browser, the xml will just display. In the Android app, could I copy the xml from the cache?

Is there any other way of downloading the xml?

Could I use a different file type, which the browser would download?

Thanks

Comment: do you just want to display xml or do you want to use it as a data stream?

Comment: I was looking to download the xml through the browser, then the app would copy this into its installed folder. The xml contains some settings specific to the customer, which would be read by the app.

Comment: are you going to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to download an xml file from a URL

```
try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file 
        URL url = new URL("http://your/path/to/file.xml");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"data.xml");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        progressDialog.setMax(totalSize);

        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();
        //catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should probably do this in the background, i.e. use an AsyncTasc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load a small xml file the Document class is fairly straight forward to use. You can use an http get request to grab the xml file. Here is a simple function you can call, pass in a url, and get a xml document object you can dig into:

```
public static Document getXML(final String url) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Document out = null;

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Document> result = executor.submit(new Callable<Document>() {
            public Document call() throws Exception {

                HttpGet uri = new HttpGet(url);

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse resp = null;
                try {
                    resp = client.execute(uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                StatusLine status = resp.getStatusLine();
                if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                    Log.d("http error", "HTTP error, invalid server status code: " + resp.getStatusLine());
                }

                // try {
                HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = null;
                try {
                    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Document dom = null;
                try {
                    dom = builder.parse(in);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return dom;
            }

        });


        try {
            out = result.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out;

    }
```